# Entity Framework Refuses to Show Which Column is "broken"

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework-4

This post is going to be riddled with problems. I know we do EF wrong. I know the way we do EF is abominable. Now that that's out of the way:

We have a number of very legacy code bases that use DB First Entity Framework. It works, it's awful but it works.

Except when something changes in a table and the model doesn't update. Since a lot of these old code bases share a data model but run their own distinct DBs, sometimes things in the Data Model changes. Like a column becomes Not Null, for example.

Then, anytime you try to access that table, it will start to break. Really the best solution is to move to Code First, but that's a pipe dream that will never materialize. So my question is how in the hell does one get EF to just tell me which column it is chocking on?

I swear I'm one more vague error of "The cast to value `blah` failed" or something similar away from throwing this PC across the room. If I'm EXTREMELY lucky, it will give me a datatype, but that's the absolute most. Most of the time, like right now, I'm digging through every column on every table in a view or the LINQ query to find that ONE COLUMN that doesn't have the right type or properties.

EF *has* to know which column it choked on, I just can't figure out how to find it and I cannot for the life of me figure out why some brilliant mind a Micro$oft thought not materializing this information in the error was a good idea, but I'm going crazy.

There has to be a way. FWIW my EF verion in the properties panel says 3.5 so I tagged this EF 4 since I could not find the EF 3.5 tag (runtime version v2.0.50727).

Comment: Maybe as a slightly different tack.  Any reason you can't use the Schema Compare tools?  Have a"known" copy of the of the DB somewhere you can use as a base to see what has changed?

Answer (score 0):

The error messages were improved in EF 6, and should allow you to get the property name as well

Comment: Unfortunately I think EF 6 has other requirements our legacy code bases don't meet, and if they do there are too many to realistically update.